# Lua - подключение модуля

Tags: lua

Доброе время суток, прошу помощи с подключение модуля `lua-utf8`. Поставил модуль с помощью luarocks, но при попытке подключения луа сыпет ошибками.

`local utf8 = require 'lua-utf8'`

[Сам модуль](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8)

---

**обновление**

Установлен Lua 5.2.3

Вывод при запуске тестовых скриптов:

```
root@10029:/home# lua 1.lua
lua: 1.lua:1: module 'lua-utf8' not found:
        no field package.preload['lua-utf8']
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lua-utf8/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lua-utf8/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lua-utf8/init.lua'
        no file './lua-utf8.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/lua-utf8.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './lua-utf8.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        1.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
root@10029:/home# lua 2.lua
lua: 2.lua:1: module 'unicode' not found:
        no field package.preload['unicode']
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/unicode.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/unicode/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/unicode.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/unicode/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/unicode.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/unicode/init.lua'
        no file './unicode.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/unicode.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/unicode.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/unicode.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './unicode.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        2.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

root@10029:~# luarocks list

Installed rocks:
----------------

luautf8
   0.1.1-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks

slnunicode
   1.1-2 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста: 1. полный вывод при запуске минимального тестового файла. 2. вывод команды `luarocks list`. // сколько (и каких) версий lua у вас установлено в системе?

Comment: 1. для того, чтобы внести исправления/дополнения в вопрос, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. вы не привели вывод команды `luarocks list`. 3. если у вас *debian-основный* дистрибутив, приведите вывод `dpkg-query -l 'lua*'`, если *redhat-основный* — `rpm -qa | grep lua`.

Comment: я обновил свой ответ, добавив инструкцию по сборке *luarocks*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно, вы что-то сделали «не так».

я протестировал (в дистрибутиве *ubuntu*) два модуля: *lua-utf8* и *slnunicode*.

обратите внимание, что при использовании *luarocks* надо указывать `luautf8`, а не `lua-utf8` (проверить имя и доступность этого пакета можно, например, с помощью команды `luarocks search utf8`).

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install luarocks
...
$ sudo luarocks install luautf8
...
luautf8 0.1.1-1 is now built and installed in /usr/local/ (license: MIT)
$ sudo luarocks install slnunicode
...
slnunicode 1.1-2 is now built and installed in /usr/local/ (license: Tcl License + MIT/X11)
```

тестовые файлы:

```
$ cat test.lua.utf8.lua
local utf8 = require('lua-utf8')
local a = "lua"
local u = "луа"
print(utf8.len(a), utf8.len(u))

$ cat test.sln.unicode.lua
local utf8 = require('unicode').utf8
local a = "lua"
local u = "луа"
print(utf8.len(a), utf8.len(u))
```

запуск:

```
$ lua test.lua.utf8.lua
3       3
$ lua test.sln.unicode.lua
3       3
```

---

**обновление**

да, действительно, «чехарда» получается из-за различных версий *lua*. точнее, из-за того, что пакет *luarocks*, судя по всему, собирается лишь для одной версии *lua*. в вашем случае, видимо, только для *5.1*.

инструкция по сборке для версии *5.2* (для *debian-основных* дистрибутивов):

1. лучше удалить пакет *luarocks*, чтобы «не мешался»:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove luarocks
   ```
2. установите пакет с заголовочными файлами для нужной версии *lua*. в моём случае пакет называется `liblua5.2-dev`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install liblua5.2-dev
   ```
3. создайте каталог, в котором будет производиться сборка. например, `~/src/luarocks` и «перейдите» в него:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/src/luarocks; cd ~/src/luarocks
   ```
4. скачайте исходники *luarocks*:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks.git .
   ```
5. выполните скрипт `./configure`, указав, какую версию *lua* следует использовать;

   ```
   $ ./configure --lua-version=5.2 --versioned-rocks-dir
   ```
6. если скрипт выполнился без ошибок, скомпилируйте программу:

   ```
   $ make build
   ```
7. и установите её:

   ```
   $ sudo make install
   ```

---

теперь можно устанавливать нужные модули:

```
$ sudo luarocks install luautf8
```